# Need simple example of FitNesse SetUpFixture under .NET

Tags: c#, fitnesse, fitsharp

I've been trying to implement FitNesse tests for our C# application. I'm using the latest FitNesse jar and the fitSharp .NET 2.2 4.0 libraries.

I have been able to successfully use scenarios using Slim. However, in the interests of making tests that are more legible to a non-technical audience, I'm interested in implementing `DoFixtures`, and I surmise I'll need `SetUpFixtures` to create common data conditions for tests.

I can't seem to get the data I set up into the `DoFixture` instance, though. I've looked at several resources ([Gojko's book](http://gojko.net/FitNesse/book/) chief among them), but none seem to talk about this concept in isolation. Attaching Visual Studio as a debugger to test runs hasn't yielded any insight. I could really use a trivial example to analyze and build upon.

Would someone be willing to share an example that includes just:

- A `SetUpFixture` class that sets up some data
- A `DoFixture` class that uses the data from the SetUpFixture
- Wiki syntax to invoke them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like SetUp was not called. Use `Debugger.Launch()` for debug

Update:

```
!|BirdCall|
|birdName|noise|
|duck|quack|

public class SkylarkBunting : fitlibrary.DoFixture
{
    public BirdCall BirdCall;

    public SkylarkBunting(BirdCall birdCall)
    {
        BirdCall = birdCall;
    }

    public string GetCall()
    {
        return BirdCall.Noise;
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return BirdCall.BirdName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry to be naive, but can you elaborate? Where would I make setup get called?

Comment: oops, sorry my fault, setup called on flow mode thru dofixture. a bit confusing call. The best way is setup data and after call method . Here is example how to setup data http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.FixtureGallery.FitLibraryFixtures.SetUpFixture

Answer (score 1):

I've got a partial answer.

Using these classes:

```
public class BirdCall : fitlibrary.SetUpFixture
{
    public void BirdNameNoise(string birdName, string noise)
    {
        BirdName = birdName;
        Noise = noise;
    }

    public string BirdName; 
    public string Noise;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("BirdCall: {0}, {1}", BirdName, Noise);
    }
}

public class SkylarkBunting : fitlibrary.DoFixture
{
    public BirdCall BirdCall;
    public string Call;

    public Fixture CryOut()
    {
        BirdCall = new BirdCall();
        Call = BirdCall.Noise;
        return BirdCall;
    }

    public string GetCall()
    {
        return BirdCall.Noise;
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return BirdCall.BirdName;
    }
}
```

and this Wiki markup:

```
!define TEST_RUNNER {C:\temp\fitsharp\Runner.exe}
!define COMMAND_PATTERN {%m -r fitnesse.fitserver.FitServer,c:\temp\fitsharp\fit.dll %p}
!path C:\temp\FitNesseIntegration\bin\Debug\FitnesseIntegration.dll

!|import|
|FitnesseIntegration|

!|FitNesseIntegration.Skylark.SkylarkBunting|

!3 Testing getting data from a setup fixture into a do fixture

!|cry out|
|bird name|noise|
|Tweetie|Caw!|

|check|call||
|check|get call||
|check|get name||
|check|bird call||
```

I get:

```
|check|call|null|
|check|get call|Caw!|
|check|get name|Tweetie|
|check|bird call|BirdCall: Tweetie, Caw!|
```

This is good, I have variables in the `DoFixture` that were populated by executing the `SetUpFixture` with values injected by FitNesse via the page.

I'd still like to know why Call returns `null`, though.

Comment: Call is null because you assign it after an instance of BirdCall has been created but before Noise has been assigned a value.